# choose which signal is connected to the slot

Tags: qt, pyside

How to use a specefic signal when there is signals that have the same name and emits different arguments.

[image]

```
buttonGroup = QButtonGroup()
buttonGroup.buttonClicked.connect( self.onButtonClicked )

@Slot(int)
def onButtonClicked(self, buttonIndex):
    self.currentFile = self.files[buttonIndex]
```

By default, the code above seems to choose the second signal ( which emits a PySide.QtGui.QPushButton element )

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/riless/main.py", line 154, in onButtonClicked
    self.currentFile = self.files[buttonIndex]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not PySide.QtGui.QPushButton
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had just to change this line:

```
buttonGroup.buttonClicked.connect( self.onButtonClicked )
```

with this one:

```
buttonGroup.buttonClicked[int].connect( self.onButtonClicked )
```